# Scheißkälte vs. scheiß Kälte

Tags: meaning

Could someone please explain what is the difference between "scheiß Kälte" and "Scheißkälte"?

My girlfriend (she is German) meant both have different meaning, but she couldn't explain how are they different.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The difference is somewhat minute.

"Scheiß Kälte" might be used when talking about the "bloody cold" and how it is affecting other activities (or whatever) simply by being cold.

"Scheißkälte" as one term might be rather used to qualify the cold itself as being extremely cold, and not so much talking about the impact of the cold onto any other activities.

I'm not convinced that this distinction is always possible or being well made by native speakers, though, including myself.

Also note, that 'Scheiße' is a rather vulgar word and you might not want to use it in every social context :)

Comment: Thank you very much. My confusion was because I've never heard Scheißkälte (zusammen geschrieben in meaning of extreme coldness), but rather scheißkalt (in meaning very cold). Maybe another confusion that in "scheiß Kälte" the word "scheiß" looked to me as an adjective, but there was no ending like "scheiß+E Kälte" (compared to "verdammt+E Kälte"). However "scheiß+E Kälte" also sounds very strange to me. Maybe it's not an adjective at all?!

Comment: @MurVotema I'd argue that "scheiß" in use as an adjective is a rare case where it is not being declined, like 'prima'.

Comment: Yes, i found even the name for it: indeklinable Adjektive

Answer (score 0):

The usage and meaning of "scheiß" here is actually as an adjective, but this is not acknowledged by Duden. So you have to write it as "Scheißkälte". "Scheiß Kälte" is wrong since compound nouns don't have a space as separator.

Comment: See the answer https://german.stackexchange.com/a/75138/1497

Comment: ... and https://de.wiktionary.org/wiki/schei%C3%9Fe

Comment: @MurVotema: What do you want? Your linked answer is not correct, and your linked Duden entry says nothing about this topic.

Comment: In one case it's not a compound noun, it's a noun with an indiklables Adjektiv

Comment: @MurVotema: no, you're not right, there is no such case mentioned. And "Scheiß Kälte" as suggested in the accepted answer is simply wrong. You have accepted a wrong answer.